# jQuery - How to determine if a parent element exists?

Tags: jquery, parent

I'm trying to dynamically and a link to an image, however I cannot correctly determine is the parent link already exists.

This is what I have,

```
if (element.parent('a'.length) > 0)
{   
      element.parent('a').attr('href', link);            
}
else
{   
      element.wrap('<a></a>');
      element.parent('a').attr('href', link);     
}
```

Where element refers to my img element and link refers to the url to use.

Every time the code runs, the else clause is performed, regardless of whether or not the img tag is wrapped in an a tag.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The first line should be:

```
if (element.parent('a').length > 0)
```

Comment: `if (element.parent('a').length)` without the `> 0` will be sufficient since any number larger than 0 will default to true.

Comment: Yes, but using `> 0` makes the code more readable and more obvious what it does, and readability goes before brevity.

Comment: "Nothing escapes you that good as the most obvious things".

I had a scenario involving `closest`, so I simply used `$el.closest(".selector").length > 0` as a condition. Damn us people for being so oblivious at times. =)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `element` is actually a jQuery object:

```
if (!element.parent().is("a")) {
  element.wrap("<a>")
}  
element.parent().attr("href", link);
```

If `element` is a DOM node:

```
if (!$(element).parent().is("a")) {
  $(element).wrap("<a>")
}  
$(element).parent().attr("href", link);
```

Comment: @cletus dominates the arena. +1

Answer (score 1):

Your code is parsed as a call to `element.parent` with the argument `'a'.length`.
It is therefore equivalent to `element.parent(1)`, which is an invalid call.

You need to get the length of the jQuery object by moving `.length` after the `)`, like this:

```
if (element.parent('a').length > 0)
```

Also, this will not work if `element` is nested in some other tag which is itself in an `<a>` tag.
You might want to call `closest` instead.